# Vector class library for processing speed

Tags: c++, sse, simd, avx, vector-class-library

I am looking at parallel processing algorithm for processing speed improvement.
I want to test [Agner Fog's vector class library, VCL](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass).

I am wondering how to select different vector classes for example `Vec16c` (SSE2 instruction set) and `Vec32c` (AVX instruction set).

I am using Intel® Atom™ x5-Z8350 Processor and according to the specs, it supports SSE4.2 instruction sets.

How can I effectively choose vector class with regards to the hardware support?
Say for my processor, can I use Vec32c recommended for AVX instruction set?

Comment: I have added a new tag: vector-class-library for questions related to the vector class library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use compiler defined macros to detect what instruction-sets are enabled for the target you're compiling for, such as:

```
// Assume SSE2 as a baseline
#include  <vectori128.h>

#if defined(__AVX2__)
#include  <vectori256.h>
using vector_type = Vec32c;
#else
// Vec16c uses whatever is enabled, so you don't have to check for SSE4 yourself
using vector_type = Vec16c;
#endif
```

This doesn't do run-time detection, so only enable AVX2 if you want to make a binary that only runs on CPUs with AVX2.

If you want your code to work on non-x86 platforms, or x86 without SSE2 where VCL isn't supported at all, you need to protect the `#include <vectori128.h>` with `#if` as well.

Comment: You'd actually want to use Vec32c if `__AVX2__` is defined, and otherwise always use `Vec16c` (and let vectorclass headers take care of using SSE4.1/4.2 / SSSE3 where useful.)  The only other thing you'd want to do with macros in your own code is check for AVX512 and use `Vec64c`.  One of the major goals of the vectorclass library is abstracting the selection of different intrinsics based on availability of different target options.

Comment: This took a pretty major edit before I could upvote it, but I'm pretty confident it's correct now.  I have actually used VCL (and [contributed changes](https://github.com/pcordes/vectorclass) (which AFAIK aren't integrated yet, and I should probably polish up so Agner can include them.))

Answer (score 4):

AVX is required for 32-byte vectors.  (And AVX2 for 32B integer vectors like `Vec32c`).  Since your Atom doesn't have AVX, don't include Agner's `vectorclassi256.h` or `vectorclassf256.h`, just the `128` headers.

Compile with `-march=native` to get the compiler to enable all the instruction-sets your host-CPU supports.

The implementations of the `Vec16c` functions will automatically use SSE4.2 intrinsics when they're enabled, because Vectorclass checks macros to see what's enabled.  So just use `Vec16c` and you will automatically get the best implementations of every function that your target supports.

(This is true since you're doing compile-time CPU / target options.  If you wanted to do run-time dispatching yourself, it would be harder.)

Answer (score 2):

The vector class library has been updated and improved. It is moved to Github:

https://github.com/vectorclass

Comment: This code can automatically detect the CPU instruction set at runtime and select the appropriate version of the code:
https://github.com/vectorclass/version2/blob/master/dispatch_example2.cpp